# Gentzen's system proof of sequent

Tags: logic

We know that in Gentzen's system $\Gamma,p\vdash \Delta,p $ is axiom.   $p$ is propositional variable.   Prove that each sequent form of $\Gamma, \phi \vdash \Delta, \phi$ is deducable in Gentzen's system.

**My trial**
Each formul can be converted into $CNF$. So let's $\phi$ will be in CNF form.  Then $\phi=(p_{11}...\vee ...p_{1k})\wedge ... \wedge (p_{n1}...\vee ...p_{n,m})$.
So, using following sequence of rules (as much as possible):
1) Right $\wedge$
2) Left $\vee$
3) No, each node of our tree have $\Gamma, x_1\vee ..\vee x_n\vdash\Delta\vee  x_1\vee ...\vee x_n$
4) Using weakness rules (left and right) (as much as possible) we have $\Gamma, x_i\vdash\Delta, x_i $, which is axiom.

Am I ok ?

Comment: Usually the proof is by induction on the *complexity* of $\phi$.

Comment: be more precisely please. What about my proof ? I dont understand what does it mean complexity of $\phi$

Comment: Idea with conversion to CNF is ok ?

Comment: Did you mean structural induction on $\phi$ ?

Comment: Ok, it works fine. What about my proof with conversion to CNF ?